# Applying className/onClick/onChange not working on Custom React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, jsx

I'm almost new to `react`. 
I'm trying to create a simple editing and creating mask.
Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Company from './Company';

class CompanyList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            search: '',
            companies: props.companies
        };
    }

    updateSearch(event) {
        this.setState({ search: event.target.value.substr(0,20) })
    }

    addCompany(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      let nummer = this.refs.nummer.value;
      let bezeichnung = this.refs.bezeichnung.value;
      let id = Math.floor((Math.random()*100) + 1);
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          context:this,
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          url: "../data/post/json/companies",
          data: ({ 
              _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
              nummer: nummer,
              bezeichnung : bezeichnung,
          }),
          success: function (data) {
            id = data.Nummer;
            this.setState({
              companies: this.state.companies.concat({id, nummer, bezeichnung})
            })
            this.refs.bezeichnung.value = '';
            this.refs.nummer.value = '';
          }
      });
    }

    editCompany(event) {
      alert('clicked');
      event.preventDefault();
      this.refs.bezeichnung.value = company.Bezeichnung;
      this.refs.nummer.value = company.Nummer;
    }

    render() {
      let filteredCompanies = this.state.companies.filter(
        (company) => {
          return company.bezeichnung.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        }
      );
        return (
        <div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">Suche</div>
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
              <div className="form-group">
                <input className="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.search} placeholder="Search" onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form onSubmit={this.addCompany.bind(this)}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">Neuen Eintrag erfassen</div>
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input className="form-control" type="text" ref="nummer" placeholder="Nummer" required />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input className="form-control" type="text" ref="bezeichnung" placeholder="Firmenname" required />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Add new company</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
              <ul>
              { 
                filteredCompanies.map((company)=> {
                  return <Company company={company} key={company.id} onClick={this.editCompany.bind(this)} />
                })
              }
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CompanyList
```

The Company class looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Company = ({company}) => 
  <li>
    {company.Nummer} {company.Bezeichnung}
  </li>


export default Company
```

My question now is, why is the `onclick` event not being fired, when I click on a `Company`.

In this part:

```
      <ul>
      { 
        filteredCompanies.map((company)=> {
          return <Company company={company} key={company.id} onClick={this.editCompany.bind(this)} className="Company"/>
        })
      }
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is pretty simple, when you onClick like

```
<Company company={company} key={company.id} onClick={this.editCompany.bind(this)} />
```

its not an event that is set on the component, rather a prop that is being passed to the `Company` component and can be accessed like `props.company` in the Company component,

what you need to do is to specify the `onClick` event and `className` in the Company component like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Company = ({company, onClick, className}) => (
  <li onClick={onClick} className={className}>
    {company.Nummer} {company.Bezeichnung}
  </li>
)

export default Company
```

The function passed on as prop to the `Company` component can be passed on by any name like

```
<Company company={company} key={company.id} editCompany={this.editCompany.bind(this)} className="Company"/>
```

and used like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Company = ({company, editCompany}) => (
  <li onClick={editCompany}>
    {company.Nummer} {company.Bezeichnung}
  </li>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But do I need to specify also the event itself then in `Company` or can I specify it also in `CompanyList` to use the controls for input? I mean the method `editCompany`.

Comment: event will be specified at the component level, so in the Company component itself, the function that you nee to call on that event can be passed on by any name

Comment: Just adding a tiny bit more explanation - I believe default HTML elements in React have an onClick property like normal HTML elements, but because custom react components are being defined by you, onClick is treated as a custom property, not a built-in onclick property

Answer (score 1):

you have to bind the event on you child component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Company = ({ company, onClick }) => 
   <li onClick={onClick}>
      {company.Nummer} {company.Bezeichnung}
   </li>


export default Company
```

or

```
const Company = ({ company, ...props }) => 
   <li {...props}>
      {company.Nummer} {company.Bezeichnung}
   </li>
```

if you want that all props passed to your Compagny component (exept compagny) goes to your li tag. see ES6 spread operator and rest.