# Adding style attribute on custom React element does not seem to pick up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-modules

I have code as follows (using CSS modules):

```
return (
  <div>
    <LandingPage className={styles.hidden} />
  </div>
);
```

Which doesn't work (i.e. doesn't apply the CSS to the element). However, returning

```
  <div>
    <div className={styles.hidden}>
      <LandingPage />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Works just fine. Why does applying a `className` on a custom element cause the class to be ignored?

Comment: what does the LandingPage component look like? you need to put that className on an html element eventually

Comment: The answer is the same as this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070162/react-why-event-is-not-being-fired/44070389#44070389

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `className` will not get applied directly on `LandingPage` component, it is basically a `props` value that you are passing from parent component to child component, you need to apply that class inside `LandingPage` component.

Like this:

```
<LandingPage customClassName={styles.hidden} />
```

Inside `LandingPage`:

```
render(){
   console.log('class name', this.props.customClassName);
   return(
       <div className={this.props.customClassName}>
           {/* other elements */}
       </div>
   )
}
```

Always remember **props is an object**, whatever data you will pass from parent will become a part of props values only, you need to use that data somewhere in child component.

Check the `console`, it will print the proper class name that you are passing from parent.