# Why doesn't individual styling of a react component instance work?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm using the following instance of a react component in a view:

```
<Jumbotron>
  Lot's of important content
</Jumbotron>
```

I want an individual style (i.e. a different background image for this instance. So this doesn't work:

```
<Jumbotron className="individual">
  Lot's of important content
</Jumbotron>
```

Wrapping the instance in a `div` also doesn't work. How can I do this with simple markup and CSS so that I can simply style the individual class in CSS? AFAIK properties won't help to customize instances...

Comment: Have you imported the file in your root container ?

Comment: where is that `css` class imported?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding style attribute on custom React element does not seem to pick up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573292/adding-style-attribute-on-custom-react-element-does-not-seem-to-pick-up) *if Jumbotron is a custom component*

Comment: If Jumbotron a React-bootstrap component then you need to specify the className as a prop `bsClass` like `<Jumbotron bsClass="individual">
  Lot's of important content
</Jumbotron>`  . See https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#jumbotron

Comment: CSS works fine for the rest of the code. Why can't I simply style that `Jumbotron` instance with an individual `className` like any other `div`?
 Applying styles to custom classes works for the rest completely fine without applying `props`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass in the style attribute or you can pass through the className attribute in the same way

```
<Jumbotron className="background--black">
```

And have your component like this -

```
const Jumbotron = ({className}) => {
    <div className={className}>
       Here is the jumbotron
    </div>
}
export default Jumbotron
```

And import a css file that has that class in, if you're using className. But I would probably recommend just using style attribute if it's a one off.