# React - click handler on child component with map not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 react components - a container (SearchBarContainer) and 2x presentational components (PostList & PostItem (child of PostList))

I am trying to attach a click handler to the post item which will bubble up to the SearchBarContainer, here is my code:

```
class SearchBarContainer extends Component {

  selectPost(post) {
    console.log('cliked');
    //this.props.dispatch(selectPost(post));
  }

  render() {

    return (

        <div>
          <div className="center-xs">
            <p>To get started, type in some keywords below</p>
          </div>

          <SearchBar onTermChange={this.props.actions.loadPosts} onNull={this.props.actions.nullPosts}/>  
          <PostList posts={this.props.posts} isFetching={this.props.isFetching} onClick={this.selectPost}/>

        </div>

    );
  }
}
```

And here is my postList:

```
const PostList = (props) => {

  const postItems = props.posts.map((singlePost) => {
    return <PostItem key={singlePost.id} post={singlePost} onClick={() => props.onClick}/>
  });

  if(!props.isFetching) {
    return (
      <div className="mt2 row list-unstyled" > {postItems}</div>
    );

  } else {
    return (
      <Loader />      
    );
  }

};

export default PostList;
```

However this click handler isnt working. I notice if I place the click handler on the div that wraps the postItems array then it does work, I think the issue is that the click handler is attached to a mapped item which is wrapped inside a div?

Here is the PostItem function:

```
const PostItem = (singlePost) => {

  return (
      <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb2 animated fadeIn">
        <div className="card rounded">
          <div className="card-header p1">
            <h4 className="card-title mt0 h5">{singlePost.post.title}</h4>
          </div>
          <img className="card-img-top img-fluid" src={singlePost.post.thumbnail} alt={singlePost.post.title} />
          <div className="card-block p1">
            {/*<p className="card-text">{singlePost.post.description}</p>*/}
            <Link to={`/product/${singlePost.post.slug}`} className="btn btn--blue flt--left w100">View More</Link>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>    

  )
};

export default PostItem;
```

I think maybe i need the click handler event to go like this:
Click (PostItem) -> pass via props (PostList) -> pass via props (SearchBarContainer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - Why event is not being fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070162/react-why-event-is-not-being-fired)

Comment: Apart from it being a duplicate, you need to make the change that @Mayank suggested in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using arrow function with onClick and not calling `props.onClick` function from its body here:

```
onClick={() => props.onClick}
```

Use this put `()`:

```
onClick={() => props.onClick()}
```

Or don't use arrow function and directly write:

`onClick = {props.onClick}`

**Update:**

Whatever we pass in props, it will become a object property-value only, we need to use it inside Child component.

You are passing the onClick function in `PostItem` but inside `PostItem` you are not using it anywhere, define the click event on any DOM Node, like this:

```
<div onClick={singlePost.onClick} ....>
```

Comment: Sorry no go, I think the issue is because the {postItems} array (and the click handler is attached to the post item) is rendered inside of the component which is expecting the click, so it is not 'bubbling' the event up the chain.

Comment: @rhysclay where you are using the onClick function inside `PostItem` component?

Comment: Sorry i was using it inside the PostItem component (I didnt think I needed to). I added it into this item and its working now, it works like this: Click (PostItem) onClick -> pass via props (PostList) -> pass via props (SearchBarContainer)

Answer (score 3):

I think you have passed onClick to component PostItem in line:

```
return <PostItem key={singlePost.id} post={singlePost} onClick={() => props.onClick}/>
```

You should pass it as prop to PostItem component and handle it there. like you are passing key and post. Do it for onClick too, like:

```
return <PostItem key={singlePost.id} post={singlePost} onClick={props.onClick}/>
```

And handle onClick prop in PostItem component.