# Override Classname Not Working in React Component

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to do a seemingly easy thing but without much luck.  I have a React app that uses the Grommet UX framework.  In the app, I use a Web Chat component which I would like to style.

The grommet style is correctly being applied for fonts but my custom changes for my web chat component are not being applied.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

App.js

```
import  '../scss/custom.scss';
...
class PatientApp extends React.Component {
...
render() {
...
<Chat className='wc-app' directline='GUID_Entered_Here />
```

Custom.scss

```
    @import 'elu.defaults.scss';
    @import '~grommet/scss/grommet-core/index.scss';

    body .wc-app, .wc-app button, .wc-app input, .wc-app textarea {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        background-color: #2AD2C9;
    }

.wc-chatview-panel {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: #2AD2C9;
}

.wc-header {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: #2AD2C9;
}

.wc-message-pane {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: #2AD2C9;
}
```

Below is a screenshot which shows the output HTML when i run my code.  On the right you will notice the classNames being referenced.

[image]

Comment: Is this Web Chat component one you made(custom) or a library you are using ?

Comment: It is a library I'm using...https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

Comment: In that case I would urge you to inspect the elements that the Chat component generates in your Browser. Figure out which parts you want to change the Font of, then use their classnames in the CSS. I presume you are not targeting the right elements with your CSS.

Comment: Probably as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070162/react-applying-classname-or-onclick-properties-to-component-doesnt-take-effec

Comment: Updated to show output screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,
I was able to get this working just had to set a height and width within the chatview panel and everything is now appearing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As the [DOCS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#styling) says:

> In the /src/scss/ folder you will find the source files for generating
>   /botchat.css. Run npm run build-css to compile once you've made your
>   changes. For basic branding, change colors.scss to match your color
>   scheme. For advanced styling, change botchat.scss.

Comment: Sagv1.  Thank you for the response.  I did not recompile the webchat component as part of my project, and rather just using the component as it is provided.  Rather I created my own custom css and am trying to import the SCSS styles as detailed in the link here.  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/646