# Should I define standard React PropTypes on my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a component library and I'm wondering if it would be best practice to define `propTypes` that I know will be commonly used even if they're **not** custom props. I've seen it done in other react component libraries (namely Material-UI) but I'm not sure why...

For example:

```
Button.propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
    ...
    type: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

const Button = (props) => <button {...props} />;
```

Here I'd obviously want to include the `type` property as it's custom to my implementation and is required by this component... but what about the other two? From my understanding, props like `className`, `onClick` are already defined on most (all?) DOM elements by React.

**With that in mind, does React type-check native DOM element properties like `onClick` (`click()`) and `className` when they are passed through to an HTML element?**

If so, including them in the propTypes object of my parent component seems redundant if they're optional.

---

**ANSWER**

After doing some testing it seems like the answer is ***no***, most of the native properties on HTML elements do not have type-checking supplied by React. Some have deprecation and other misc. warnings but, by-and-large, types are not enforced (or suggested) on native props so you **SHOULD** include them in your components.

See [Shubham's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514426/should-i-define-standard-react-proptypes-on-my-component/48514535#48514535) in the comments for more info...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the **[documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)**:

> As your app grows, you can catch a lot of bugs with typechecking.
>   React `PropTypes` exports a range of validators that can be used to
>   make sure the data you receive is valid.
>
> When an invalid value is provided for a prop, a warning will be shown
>   in the JavaScript console. For performance reasons, `propTypes` is
>   only checked in development mode.

The point of having proptypes is to let you know during development that certain props are received by a component and some of them may be required, without passing them your code will break

You might also use JavaScript extensions like `Flow` or `TypeScript` to typecheck your whole application which provide greater flexibility. Read this section on **[Static TypeChecking](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html)** in the React docs for more details

Also considering you are asking if you should check native DOM element properties like `onClick` and `className`, you need to check these as well since they are not native DOM elements on your custom components but passed as props to it. Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070162/applying-classname-onclick-onchange-not-working-on-custom-react-component/44070389#44070389)** answer for more details

Comment: I've updated my question. I read through the documentation prior to posting here and understand why to use typechecking... 

I'm trying to figure out if certain properties are redundant to include in my typechecking.

Comment: My solution was added to the question but I'm accepting this as the answer for anyone who may be looking for additional info. Thanks @ShubhamKhatri

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the whole point of having propTypes defined for a component is to help you ( and your fellow team mates ) document the component API you've created. This means that by reading the propTypes you can know what to send to a component for it to work as expected. Also props validation in DEV mode helps you when someone passes a different type for the prop defined.

So to answer your question, for a component library you should take that bullet and define your abstractions explicitly.

PS: you can always pass more props then defined in PropTypes, but then there are better patterns which you can incorporate.

Comment: I updated my question, but I'm leaning towards this answer regardless. Seems like it makes most sense to just define anything that could be used, native DOM element property or not...