# Why my React component handler is executed at render time and will not work afterwhile?

Tags: reactjs

My App component:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import Library from './Library'

  class App extends Component {

    state = {
      library: storeGet() || {},
      lib_img_selected : null
    };

    selectedLibImgHandler = (url) => {
      console.log('url', url)
    };


    render() {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <Library  mylibrary={this.state.library} onSelectedImage={this.selectedLibImgHandler} />
          </div>
        </div>

      );
    }
  }

  export default App;
```

I have this component Library :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import Card from './Card'

  class Library extends Component {
      imageSelected = (udsUrl) =>{
        console.log('clicked')

      }
        getPreviews = () => {
        // console.log('this.props.library', this.props.mylibrary)
        var self = this;
        var cards = Object.keys(this.props.mylibrary).map(function (key, index) {
          let x = self.props.mylibrary[key];
          let card = {}
          card.uid = x.id
          card.title = x.customImageName || 'Img ' + index
          card.src = 'http://myurl';
          card.url = 'http://....'

          return card
        });
        return cards;
      }
      render() {

        return (
          <div className="row">
            <div className="jumbotron" >
              <h1>Library</h1>
              {this.getPreviews().map(card => <Card key={card.uid} {...card} onClick={this.imageSelected(card.url) }/>)}


            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }

  }

  export default Library;
```

Card is something like this:

```
import React  from 'react';
const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className='card-box'>
            <div className='card-image'>
                <img src={props.src} alt="" className={props.orientation} />
            </div>
            <div>{props.title}</div>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Card;
```

I don't get why

```
 onClick={this.imageSelected(card.url)
```

is being fired for every Card component rendered  and then when I click on a Card nothing happens..

I think I'm missing some core concept about rendering and function bindings with React...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onClick` needs a function, the way you are using it, you are assigining the returned value of imageSelected to onClick which isn't a function and thus on every render it is executed. Use it like

```
onClick={() => this.imageSelected(card.url)}
```

Also the `click` events are registered on components, instead it is passed on as props to the component. You need to assign the click event to card like

```
const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className='card-box' onClick={props.onClick}>
            <div className='card-image'>
                <img src={props.src} alt="" className={props.orientation} />
            </div>
            <div>{props.title}</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Check this answer for more details [Applying className/onClick/onChange not working on Custom React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070162/applying-classname-onclick-onchange-not-working-on-custom-react-component/44070389#44070389)

---

In general, if you need to pass on all the props passed from parents, you can use the following syntax:

```
<div className='card-box' {...props}>
```

Destructuring all the `props` would ensure that the props are passed and this, you won't need to do it manually for each prop.

Comment: Awesome. But if I go for .... <div className='card-box' {...props}>
How about : getPreviews() having card.onClick = () => {self.imageSelected(uds_url)} . And then           {this.getPreviews().map(card => <Card key={card.uid} {...card} />)} and finally <div className='card-box' {...props}> ?

Comment: Generally I wouldn't recommend the second approach since it will lead to all props being passed on to the div which is unwanted. You may choose to use it in special cases where props being passed on to the Card are actually the props that need to be passed to the div