# Don't understand why onclick event not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, imageicon

I've been given a gallery with images. On each image there are 3 icons which are suppose to do action when you click on them. I'm trying to activate onclick event on the image-icons but nothing happens. The image-icons are created in render function with font-awsome. I'm new to JavaScript.

I've been trying to search other questions here on the site, but none of the solutions worked for me.

the function i want to activate:

```
setNewSize() {

    const size = 500
    this.setState({
            size
        });

  }
```

problem here:

```
 render() {
   return (
     <div
       className="image-root"
       style={{
         backgroundImage: `url(${this.urlFromDto(this.props.dto)})`,
         width: this.state.size + 'px',
         height: this.state.size + 'px'
       }}
       >
       <div>

         <FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="clone" title="clone"/>  
         <FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="filter" title="filter" />
         <FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="expand" title="expand" onclick={ this.setNewSize} />
       </div>


     </div>
   );
 }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

React uses the CamelCase convention, so you should put `onClick={this.setNewSize}` instead of `onclick={this.setNewSize}`. Does that work for you?

Comment: This is not a correct answer although it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is `onclick={ this.setNewSize}`

In react, It should be **onClick**, Change like this;

*Handling events in React is similar to handling events in HTML but there are a few key differences:*

1. React events are named using camelCase while HTML events are often referred to using lowercase
2. In JSX you pass a function as the event handler rather than then function name (string)
3. You cannot return false to prevent default behavior in react. Instead you should call e.preventDefault();

hope it helps, and Don’t forget to bind methods.

Comment: This is not a correct answer although it will solve the problem.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri can you provide an explanation of why ? it might help.

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use onClick but also don't forget to bind the setNewSize you can do this in three ways

1.`onclick={ this.setNewSize.bind(this)}`

2.`constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.setNewSize = this.setNewSize.bind(this);
}`
3. `const setNewSize = () => {....}`

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to know

1. FontAwesome is a custom react component either written by you or used from a library
2. The attributes passed to a custom react component are passed on to the component as props and unless used within the component and passed on to the DOM elements they won't have any effect. To know more about this check [this post](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070162/applying-classname-onclick-onchange-not-working-on-custom-react-component/44070389#44070389)

   3.You must bind methods either in the constructor or using arrow function to use `this` correctly within it.

To solve the above problem, you need to check the documentation of the component if you are using it from a library and see what prop it takes to process an onClick event. In all probability, it will be `onClick` in camel case.

If you have written the component yourself, make sure you follow the instructions from the linked post to solve the problem ie. pass on the prop as an even to the DOM element.